# Mongo aggregate $slice for subdocs

Tags: mongodb

Given docs like this:

```
var user = { 
  _id: '53176dc214d1f0d0ec42ae54',
  friends: [ '53176dc214d1f0d0ec42ae54', '5317766614d1f0d0ec42ae5e' ]
};
```

I would like, in an aggregate pipeline, to return both count of each friends (as friend_total) as well as the first 10 friends ids.

I have this so far which returns the data I want - I need the equivalent of $slice for friends though.

```
{
  $unwind: '$posters',
}, {
$group: {
  _id: '$_id',
  posters:{$push:'$posters'},
  sum: {
    $sum: 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately (as at MongoDB 2.6) there is no equivalent of `$slice` for the aggregation pipeline. The relevant feature request to upvote/watch in the MongoDB issue tracker is [SERVER-6074: Allow $slice operator in $project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074).

#### Suggested workaround

There are some less savoury workarounds such as returning the full friend list in aggregation and truncating the arrays in your application code, or running multiple queries to `find()` and `$slice` related friend lists. My assumption is that your users are expected to average a lot more than 10 friends, so you want this query to be efficient.

I think your best approach for this would be to *denormalise*. Rather than relying on aggregation pipelines to produce your first 10 friend IDs, save these into a [capped array](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/58782996153/push-to-sorted-array) in your user document and maintain this array as new friends are added/removed. This does involve some duplication of data but will be fast & simple to query. Similarly, you could use `$inc` to update a `friend_count` of the friends for each user as the friends are added/removed.

With this approach you would no longer need to use `aggregate()` to calculate friend counts & first ten friends, and could use the `friend_count` for sorting or as the basis for other queries or reporting.

So your user documents would instead look like:

```
var user = { 
   _id: ObjectId("53176dc214d1f0d0ec42ae54"),
   friends: [ObjectId("53176dc214d1f0d0ec42ae54"), ObjectId("5317766614d1f0d0ec42ae5e")],
   friend_count: 2,
   topten: [ObjectId("53176dc214d1f0d0ec42ae54"), ObjectId("5317766614d1f0d0ec42ae5e")],
};
```